# Are any of the claims about the Quran in this skeptics post accurate?

Tags: quran, tafseer

There is a post on sister site [Did all iron on Earth come from outer space?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/41234/45610), it makes several claims about "facts" in the Quran.  It does not include any references to the Quran, so I wonder if this shocking fact is true or misrepresented.

## Begin copy and paste from source

According to the video [9 Shocking Facts from the Quran!](https://youtu.be/ypXqqdPrYQQ?t=2m18s)

> Iron is not natural to the Earth. It did not form on the Earth but came down to Earth from outer space. This may sound strange but it is true. Scientists have found that billions of years ago the Earth was stuck (sic) by meteorites. These meteorites were carrying iron from distant stars which has exploded.

The presenter then relates this fact with a verse from the Quran ([57:25](https://legacy.quran.com/57/25)).

> We sent down Iron with it's great inherent strength and its many benefits for humankind.

Did iron form on Earth? Did it come from outer space? Was all iron on Earth added after the Earth formed?

## End Copy and paste from source

The title of the skeptics post says that all iron on Earth is from meteorites. Reading the full verse ([57:25](https://legacy.quran.com/57/25)), I don't see anything that says "ALL" iron on earth is from meteorites, clearly some is.

Has there ever been a scholars interpretation that all Iron on earth is from meteorites?

Comment: It clearly quotes a relevant verse of the qur'an so your question is meaningless (I've just linked the verse) unless you want to know how do the early scholars interpret that part.

Comment: @Medi1Saif (thank you for the verse reference) the title of the skeptics post says that all iron on Earth is from meteorites. Reading the link you add to my question, I don't see anything that says "ALL" iron on earth is from meteorites, clearly some is.  Has there ever been a scholars interpretation that all Iron on earth is from meteorites?

Comment: You should add this infromation to clarify your question!

Comment: Note that there is also an interpretation that "sent down" means "created", as used in [7:26](https://quran.com/7/26?translations=84) and [39:6](https://quran.com/39/6?translations=84).

Comment: Honestly speaking it is rather doubtful that earlier scholars even considered such an interpretation. Even if "sent down" or "أُنزل" literally means "is sent down" or "let down/fall". The qur'an in other verses uses other meanings. Ibn Kathir for example didn't interpret the verse literally but concluded in it a reference to the permission to fight (with iron: referring to weapons made of it like swords).

Comment: @Medi1Saif I updated my question from the comments. Until a few minutes ago there were 3 answers on the skeptics post, all ignoring the obvious (to me) point of if the qur'an even made the claims suggested.  There is now a [fourth answer that brings into question the sources interpretation](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/44302/45610)